# CFDocument PDF not showing Japanese data

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, cfdocument

I have created a pdf with Japanese content using CFDocument. But It does not showing the Japanese data. I have used pageEncoding as utf-8. It showing only blank space instead of Japanese data.

I have used the following code,

```
    <cfcontent type="application/pdf">
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=test.pdf">
    <cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
    <cfdocument format="PDF" localurl="yes" marginTop=".25" marginLeft=".25" marginRight=".25" marginBottom=".25" pageType="custom" pageWidth="8.5" pageHeight="10.2">
    <cfoutput>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <title>PDF Export Example</title>
     <style>
      body { font-family: Verdana; }
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>PDF Export Example</h1>
    <p>担当するクライエントの大半は様々な規模の企業だが、カナダの大学や政府関連の研究機関の担当経験もある。
    </p>
    <h1>PDF Export English Example</h1>
    <p>This is an example.
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    </cfoutput>
    </cfdocument>
```

Please help!

Comment: I can replicate what you see, FWIW. If I remove the PDF-specific stuff it renders as HTML fine, but just won't work as PDF. Via either ColdFusion or Railo.

Comment: Yes its works fine with html. The problem is based on rendering the data into pdf

Answer (score 3):

It seems Verdana's implementation when used in PDF doesn't support Chinese / Japanese. However [it looks like `MingLiU` does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts#Ming). I just changed it to use that font, and everything worked OK via ColdFusion 10. It still didn't work in Railo, but I assume that's a Railo problem, not a PDF / font problem.

So, anyway, just use a font that specifically supports the glyphs you need to render.

Comment: I just installed [MingLiU](http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-%E7%B4%B0%E6%98%8E%E9%AB%94+MingLiU) font in Coldfusion 8. But still the problem persists for me.

Comment: [shrug]. It def *can* be made to work. I just tested on CF8. You did remember to change the CSS in the code, too, right?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have checked it here and its working for the font that I have mentioned in the code `(担当するクライエントの大半は様々な規模の企業だが、カナダの大学や政府関連の研究機関の担当経験もある。) `. But It will not work for some font like `フェザーストンホーのチェア`

Comment: I don't quite understand how that can be, given there's a coupla glyphs in the second string that appear in the first string too, eg: ト, の. Also... the second string also renders fine for me in CF8. I can only suggest experimenting with other fonts which support Japanese characters. Beyond that I'm void of ideas.

Comment: As you said, the Verdana implementation when used in PDF doesn't support Japanese contents/ [combined contents of Japanese & English](http://tiny.cc/izzq8w).

But the above strings will work when we use the font [SimSun](http://tiny.cc/m0zq8w). I have changed the code by using the font and its working fine for me. (The font MingliU not working for some cases)

I am not sure that using SimSun font is the way to solve this issue ( It may fails when we use some other japanese data it seems). That's why this is a comment rather than answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something I ran into years ago.

> In order to have the Chinese or Japanese characters rendered up
>   correctly in PDF using and , you should first check what's your
>   default locale at ColdFusion Administrator -> Setting Summary -> Java
>   Default Locale.  One would have thought CFML will respect custom
>   locale using setLocale(), but it doesn't.
>
> If it is "en_US", edit /lib/cffont.properties.  Otherwise, create a
>   /lib/cffont.properties.#locale#(e.g. /lib/cffont.properties.zh_TW ) 
>   using cffont.properties as reference.
>
> Replace the font(s) after '=' with system's Chinese font (e.g.
>   MingLiu) for Chinese or system's Japanese font (e.g. MS UI Gothic) for
>   Japanese respectively, assuming ColdFusion is installed on Windows,
>   and client has the respective font(s) installed.

http://henrylearnstorock.blogspot.ca/2010/08/how-to-render-chinese-japanese.html

Comment: I have already tried Language Culturing methods (cffont.properties.ja). But Still I am facing the issue. But it works when I have tried by using the below style body { font-family: SimSun, sans-serif; }. Also I am facing the same issue when using [Japanese content with English content](http://tiny.cc/izzq8w) even I have tried the same.